# Understanding NDI & FFmpeg Fallout

Tags: ffmpeg, compile

Recently I started looking for a way to get my capture cards to FFmpeg and OBS simultaneously, I'd like to live stream using OBS but at the same time record each input separately with FFmpeg.

Upon a little bit of research NDI seemed like the perfect solution, I could just apply the NDI filter to each source in OBS and pick them back up in FFmpeg. Unfortunately it looks like FFmpeg rescinded support for NDI because they were distributing a "non-free" version of FFmpeg.

However, I found this thread about someone compiling FFmpeg with NDI seemingly after NDI support ended:
https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite/issues/1060

Is this just because they're just using an older version of FFmpeg or can you still manually compile FFmpeg with the NDI SDK for personal use?

Trying to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That linked thread is from January 2019. NDI support was removed on March 20 2019 - that means all the supporting code, so you'll need an older build.